# How Do I Make A Random Fill In The Blanks Quiz In PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to make a quiz with a random fill in the blanks function.

Eg.

> A [25-50] year old [male,female], presents with [right iliac fossa,
>   central abdominal, left flank] pain.

So the program should randomly pick a number/word from between the `[]`

So the question should come out as
eg.

> A 27 year old female, presents with central abdominal pain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For generating random numbers - use `rand` function, for generating in range `[25-50]`:

```
$rand_age = rand(25, 50);
```

For selecting random value from array of values - use `array_rand()`, which returns random key from your source array:

```
$values = array('right iliac fossa', 'central abdominal', 'left flank');
$rand_key = array_rand($values);
$rand_string = $values[$rand_key];
```

Comment: Thanks you very much :)